# Crear un meme a partir de una imagen y enviarlo por Whatsapp objective-c IOS

Tags: imagen, objective-c, text, whatsapp

Este es un ejemplo básico de cómo se puede crear un meme a partir de una imagen, manteniendo el tamaño actual de la imagen, y aumentando un espacio en blanco arriba y debajo de la imagen, lugar donde se escribirá el titulo y subtitulo, y compartirlo a WhatsApp.

**Imagen a trabajar** 
[image: Imagen a trabajar]

**Imagen resultante**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Puedes o no compartirlo por WhatsApp o solo trabajar con la imagen que se te devuelve.**

**CompartirImagen.m**

```
- (IBAction)compartirWhatsapp:(id)sender {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

        UIImage *img = _imagenSeleccionada.imagen; //Recupero la imagen que la tengo en un object
        NSString *textoUP=@"Mientras tanto";
        NSString *textoDown=@"En Rusia";

        //Mando los datos al método que me devolverá la imagen editada
        //CompartirImagen es el nombre de tu clase donde esta el metodo 
        //en mi caso es CompartirImagen.m
        UIImage *iconImage = [CompartirImagen drawText:textoUP drawText:textoDown inImage:img];

        //se abrirá WhatsApp para enviar la imagen
        NSString * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

        //Aqui va tu UIDocumentInteractionController 
        _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
        _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
        _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;        
        [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];

    } else {
        //Alert que indica que no tienes WhatsApp instalado
    }
}
```

**En el mismo archivo CompartirImagen.m nuestro metodo**

```
+(UIImage*)  drawText:(NSString*)text1 drawText:(NSString*)text2 inImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-BoldItalic" size:25];

    CGSize areaTrabajo =CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height+100);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(areaTrabajo );

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,50,image.size.width,image.size.height)]; //Para mostrar la imajen
    CGRect text1_rect =  CGRectMake(0,10,image.size.width, image.size.height); //para el texto titulo
    CGRect text2_rect =  CGRectMake(0,image.size.height+60,image.size.width, image.size.height); //para el texto subtitulo


    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [text1.uppercaseString drawInRect: CGRectIntegral(text1_rect)
                     withAttributes:@{
                                      NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
                                      }];

    [text2.uppercaseString drawInRect: CGRectIntegral(text2_rect)
                       withAttributes:@{
                                        NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
                                        }];
    UIImage *nuevaImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return nuevaImage;
}
```

Comment: Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien.